# Optimizing union all query oracle 11G?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone have a look in optimizing this query. Same complex query joined multiple time with UNION ALL having "last Updated Date" condition different in every set.
i can shorten below query by adding one condition without repeating the same query, which will give the same result **but** query runs 10 times longer

```
(
AND dist_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    OR line_locations_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
       OR line_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
          OR head_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
             OR releases_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') )
```

Query is given below:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   table 1.. table 8
 WHERE

      dist_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 /*all join conditions here */

 UNION ALL
 SELECT
     *
 FROM
    table 1.. table 8
 WHERE
      dist_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
     AND line_locations_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
     /*all join conditions here */
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
     *
 FROM
     table 1.. table 8
 WHERE

     dist_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
     AND line_locations_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
     AND line_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 /*all join conditions here */
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
     *
 FROM
    table 1.. table 8
 WHERE
      dist_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
     AND line_locations_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
     AND line_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
     AND head_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  /*all join conditions here */    
 SELECT
     *
 FROM
    table 1.. table 8
WHERE
    dist_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    AND line_locations_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        AND line_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            AND head_all.last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                AND releases_all.last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 /*all join conditions here */
```

Comment: Optimizing a query would require some knowledge about the table structure, the indexes, the approximate number of records ofr each involved table, the actual execution plan, ... Without these informations, it's really hard try to guess the best way to scan tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH DTL AS
(
    SELECT da.last_update_date as da_last_update_date,
            lla.last_update_date as lla_last_update_date,
            line_all.last_update_date as la_last_update_date,
            head_all.last_update_date as ha_last_update_date,
            releases_all.last_update_date as ra_last_update_date,
            .......
    FROM head_all ha
            INNER JOIN dist_all da on (ha.header_id = da.header_id)
            INNER JOIN line_all la on (da.line_id = la.line_id )
            INNER JOIN line_locations_all lla on (da.line_location_id = lla.line_location_id )
            LEFT JOIN req_distributions_all rda on (rda.distribution_id = da.req_distribution_id)
            LEFT JOIN requisition_lines_all rla on (rda.requisition_line_id = rla.requisition_line_id) 
            LEFT JOIN requisition_headers_all rha on (rla.requisition_header_id = rha.requisition_header_id)
            LET JOIN releases_all ra on (lla.release_id = ra.release_id) 
            LEFT JOIN head_all contract on (la.contract_num = contract.segment1) 
            LEFT JOIN head_all blanket_agreement on (la.from_header_id = blanket_agreement.header_id)
            LEFT JOIN line_types_b ltb on (lla.line_id = ltb.line_type_id)
    WHERE line_locations_all.shipment_type NOT IN ( 'PRICE BREAK', 'PLANNED' ) 
    AND head_all.type_lookup_code IN ( 'BLANKET', 'STANDARD', 'PLANNED' ) 
)
Select * from dtl
Where da_last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * from dtl
Where da_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND lla_last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * From dtl
Where da_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND lla_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND la_last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * From dtl
Where da_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND lla_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND la_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND ha_last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * From dtl
WHERE da_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND lla_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND la_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND ha_last_update_date <= TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
AND ra_last_update_date > TO_DATE('07/01/2018 00:00:01','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Note: in the with clause all the other required column should be listed with proper alias name (that's why I have put ....)

Comment: Above query is way too slow than the previous one. This might be because out of 8 ,5 tables joined contains 8-9 million data each and 100+ columns in each.. hence the CTE has to first create huge(whole) result set and then filter it..